# MongoServerError: Limit value must be non-negative

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I'm stuck when I get an error like this, I've been looking everywhere for a solution but haven't gotten any results. Please help me. thank you**

Product.js "Routes"

```
router.get("/products/total/", productsCount)
```

Product.js "Controller"

```
exports.productsCount = async (req, res) => {
  let total = await Product.find({}).limit(0).estimatedDocumentCount().exec();
  res.json(total);
}
```

My error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4XUs.png)

Comment: I think you can use db.collection.countDocuments(query, options)? here you are putting limit as 0 which is incorrect I think. link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments

Comment: still error and error message always appears in console "MongoServerError: Limit value must be non-negative, but received: -9223372036854775808"

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use "countDocuments" to get the count,

You can use this:

```
const count = await Product.countDocuments(query);
```

Examples:

```
const count = await Product.countDocuments({ categoryId : 'TEST' });
```

Or

```
Product.countDocuments({ categoryId : 'TEST' }, function (err, count) {
  console.log('Products count = ', count);
});
```

You can use below aggregation in mongodb 3.6

```
const result = await Product.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "totalData": [
      { "$match": { categoryId : 'TEST' }}
    ],
    "totalCount": [
      { "$count": "count" }
    ]
  }}
])
```

with skip and limit

```
const result = await Product.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "totalData": [
      { "$match": { categoryId : 'TEST' }},
      { "$skip": 10 },
      { "$limit": 10 }
    ],
    "totalCount": [
      { "$count": "count" }
    ]
  }}
])
```

Comment: still error and error message always appears in console "MongoServerError: Limit value must be non-negative, but received: -9223372036854775808"